# Azure SQL Database rename fails (Error 1801: already exists) but DB does not exist

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure-sql-database, ssms

I am attempting to rename an Azure SQL DB using SSMS (both via UI and ALTER).

I get an 1801: Database 'mydatabase' already exists. Choose a different database name.

However it seems to not exist (verified via Azure portal and attempting to connect using SSMS).

An hour or so ago I attempted to create a new DB called 'mydatabase' from import from BACPAC, using SSMS.  The process seemed to not be progressing so I cancelled/aborted.  I think this has caused some element(s) of the 'mydatabase' to be created.

I repeated the import using a different DB name 'mydatabaseNEW'.  When attempting to rename 'mydatabaseNEW' to 'mydatabase' I get this error.

The original 'mydatabase' cannot be seen.  I cannot DROP the db (even when connected to master) or make any connection to it using the SQL Server admin account.

Appreciate ideas on how I can resolve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I withdraw my question.

It may have been a matter of time, as the rename attempt has just worked successfully.  Was about 1 hour since the aborted import.  I assume somewhere between Azure and SQL that there was a clean up.